# Using Contains in Lambda with a IQueryable object and a Anonymous field

Tags: c#, entity-framework, lambda

So after reading several post about how to use `Contains` in `Lambda` I can't seem to get this to work. It should be straightforward but I am struggling big time with this up to the point where I am about to just rewrite it in Dapper.

**The problem is as follow:**
I have a data object (build with `EntityFramework`) which retrieves some data from the database, this data is being saved in a variable of type `IQueryable<a>`:

```
var data = raw.Select(p => new 
    {
        Id = p.Id,
        StatusId = p.StatusId,
        ProjectName = p.Room.Department.Project.Name,
        ProjectId = p.Room.Department.Project.Id,
        DepartmentName = p.Room.Department.Name,
        DateCreated = p.DateCreated,
        RoomName = p.Room.Name,
        UserCreatedName = p.UserCreated.Firstname + (string.IsNullOrEmpty(p.UserCreated.Insertion) ? string.Empty : " ") + p.UserCreated.Insertion + " " + p.UserCreated.Lastname,
        Comment = p.Comment,
    });
```

In some circumstances I need to filter the data, this filter is a `list` of certain project Id's:

```
List<Right> rights = Rights.GetItems(userId).ToList();
var projectIds = rights.Select(x => x.ItemId);
```

The data object should only return records which match the id's of the `projectIds list`.

Though for some reason I can't do this:

```
data = data.Where(p => x.ProjectId.Contains(projectIds);
```

The `ProjectId` field does not have a `Contains` overload, is this because it is a `Anonymous type`?

I am working in an `MVC 5` project (`.NET 4.7`).

Comment: Did you want to write `projectIds.Contains(x.ProjectId)` perhaps?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suspect you want to check your projectsIds list contains the project id, instead of trying to see if the projectId contains your list of project ids?

So try this?

```
data = data.Where(p => projectIds.Contains(p.ProjectId));
```

The projectId is most likely int, string or guid? the Contains method is an extension method for type generic IEnumerable. The ProjectId is most likely not an IEnumerable and therefore it does not have the overload. [Contains](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.contains?view=netframework-4.8)

Comment: Your absolutely right. I was overthinking this and looking at it the wrong way, in the end it is prety straightforward, thank you. And also thank you for the information about the `Contains` method as well!